# Display Linkedin posts of a sepcific company in ionic mobile app

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

I want to display the posts of a specific company and display it on html, any idea how to integrate in ionic app[image]

Comment: LinkdIn API is a good place to start: https://developer.linkedin.com/product-catalog

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LinkedIn [API](https://developer.linkedin.com/product-catalog) as Flo said, or you can scrap the info straight from the web.

NPM has a library for this: [linkedin-profile-scraper](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linkedin-profile-scraper)